# Measuring Volumes using DEMs

Tags: qgis, dem, volume

I've done quite a bit of research here and elsewhere and am still having trouble coming up with a solution for measuring volumes using a DEM derived from high-resolution (1 m) stereo satellite imagery.

The closest solution I have found so far has been this: "[How to calculate the volume of several DEMs to obtain elevation and volume changes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60030/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-several-dems-to-obtain-elevation-and-volume-chang)".

I understand that the 3D analyst extension within ArcGIS would be able to accomplish this, however, I am limited to the availability of open source software such as QGIS which I am an active user of.

Comment: A first approximation is just the sum of the DEM values multiplied by the area of a DEM pixel, when you use the same units for each. That should be doable in the QGIS expression calculator...

Comment: look at [How much rock was erupted from Mt St Helens?](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2014/5/6/how-much-rock-was-erupted-from-mt-st-helens.html) in Python only

Answer (score 3):

QGIS can use the GRASS GIS and SAGA GIS tools that solve the problem (example uses GRID VOLUME by SAGA GIS from processing).
[image]

Comment: pigreco, i can't find those tools in the SAGA

Comment: Raster volume searches - they probably changed the name