# calculating a volume from points

Tags: raster, field-calculator, 3d, grids-graticules, volume

[image: screenshot of project]

I am trying to calculate the amount of water in this reservoir. The green dots are water depths in meters (possitive value). The water depth at the edges of the reservoir is 0.

How can this be done using QGIS?

Comment: By asking about both QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop within this question, I think you have made it too broad for focused Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS-Create a polygon that represents the outer boundary of the reservoir.  Give create a new attribute in that polygon (say 'z') and populate the attribute wit the elevation. Feed the points (as mass points) and the polygon (as a hard break) into Create TIN using the z values as the elevation values.  You can convert the TIN to a raster surface and finally use the Surface Volume tools to determine the volume at the lake level when the depths were collected.
In QGIS there is a TIN interpolation method which will get you from points to Raster in one step.  You would need to clip the output to the polygon-I am sure there are similar tools as described above [Measuring Volumes using DEMs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192511/measuring-volumes-using-dems).

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have much experience with doing this sort of thing, but I have a few suggestions.

If you have a DEM, you could try the QGIS/SAGA GIS [Grid Volume Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_calculus/gridvolume.html) on it with the method set to 1 and level set to 0.0 (default). The result will display in the log messages panel (processing tab). In QGIS 2.14 the tool seems to be called Raster Volume.

With ArcGIS, you could create a TIN from the points and use the [Surface Volume (3D Analyst) Tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Surface_Volume_(3D_Analyst)) to calculate volume.